# setting custom viewerProcess fails

Tags: python, menu, process, nuke

I am trying to set my viewerProcess option to be 'Show Primary Grade' instead of 'Film' whenever my nuke is booted

However, due to the limiting information I am able to find on the net, I tried inserting the following code `nuke.knobDefault("viewerProcess", "Show Primary Grade")` in the init.py but I am unable to get it covered, much less not knowing if the code I have written is right or wrong.

As the `Show Primary Grade` is a custom plugin that my workplace is using (it is shown in this naming in the list of selection), is there any ways to check and make sure that I am writing it right?
Oh and by the way, am I able to set its script Editor to be like Maya, where whenever the user clicks on something, it will display the results in the output field?

Answer (score 1):

The correct command for setting a default Viewer Process is:

```
nuke.knobDefault('Viewer.viewerProcess', 'Show Primary Grade')
```

If that's not working, be sure the name you pass is exactly as registered. To check the registered names, run this command:

```
nuke.ViewerProcess.registeredNames()
```

Which by default returns:

```
['None', 'sRGB', 'rec709']
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I presumed the code you have written is to be wrote inside the /nuke7.0/plugins/init.py file? Secondly, in regards to the `registeredNames`, I am unable to generate any info as it is stated as `[]` in the output (probably whoever codes the custom item also affects the default items as well?) Otherwise, do you perhaps have any other solutions that can aids me in finding out the registered pass names?

Comment: What happens when you try it in an interactive session in the script editor?

Comment: Erm, what do you mean and how do I do that? Sorry about asking such noob questions

Comment: Launch nuke, open the script editor, paste the line of code in the bottom half, press ctrl+enter, and see the output in the top half

Comment: Oh.. Yup, did that, I am getting no results at all as it is displayed as `# Result:`

Comment: When you open a viewer, does it have any viewer process choices? Even the defaults?

Comment: Yes, it do have a list of choices - None, sRGB, Gamma 2.2, Film, Film (Show Primary Grade)... By default, it always choose Film as the viewerProcess

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I have to write out inside the `menu.py` file instead of `init.py` file.
And for some reasons, the naming convention - 'Show Primary Grade' works despite me unable to find the pass name for it even though I am able to track down its gizmo file...